# Proving that an adjacency transposition is the product of odd number of adjacencies.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

A transposition in $S_n$ of the form $(i \ i + 1)$ is called an
adjacency. I am trying to prove that, Given $i ∈ \{1, . . . , n − 1\}$, if $i < j$, the transposition $(i \ j)$ is a product of an odd
number of adjacencies.

How can I do this? I have been trying to factor $S_n$ to show it has odd parity but this is getting me no where.

Answer (score 2):

First shows that every transposition is a product of adjacencies (leaving the odd part for another move) :

$$(1,3)=(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)$$

$$(1,4)=(3,4)(1,3)(3,4)$$

$$(1,5)=(4,5)(1,4)(4,5)$$

Now I claim that this easily leads to an induction process showing that $(1,j)$ is always a product of adjacencies...

Now use $(i,j)=(1,i)(1,j)(1,i)$ to show that any transposition is always a product of adjacencies.

For the odd number of adjacencies, just use the signature of a permutation, which is known to be a group morphism.